# Расшифровка букв

Tags: php

Помогите с расшифровкой букв. Есть [такой каталог](http://taobao-0.com/cat/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-/-%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%84%D1%8B-/-%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F/51940009.html?order_by=price_asc). Выдача идет [отсюда](http://taobao-0.com/catalog.php?cid=50099312&page_no=1&catalogAjax=1&old_cid=50099312&act=get_load).

В первый массив `name` идут слова `ВСЕ ТОВАРЫ`

`name: "ВСЕ ТОВАРЫ"`
`"name":"\u0412\u0421\u0415 \u0422\u041e\u0412\u0410\u0420\u042b"`

Строка как-то странно зашифрована. Как это можно это расшифровать?
С помощью php?

Comment: это не зашифровано, это json, оформлено [по стандарту](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7), на php вам надо просто сделать json_decode и вы получите данные в нужном виде

Comment: Спасибо. по пробую)

Comment: Обратите еще внимание на второй параметр в json_decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print_r(json_decode('{"t":"\u0412\u0421\u0415 \u0422\u041e\u0412\u0410\u0420\u042b"}'));
```